# Capybara InfiniteRedirectError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, bdd

I am getting the same behavior whether it's in the browser or running rspec... How can this issue get resolved?

I have tried removing the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` within application_controller.rb and the result remains the same. The failing example is the very first one within spec/features/subdomain_feature_spec.rb

---

```
Failures:

1) subdomains redirects invalid accounts
 Failure/Error: visit root_url(subdomain: 'random-subdomain')

 Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError:
   redirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects.
 # /home/benny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:41:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
 # /home/benny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:22:in `visit'
 # /home/benny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:43:in `visit'
 # /home/benny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:254:in `visit'
 # /home/benny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/subdomain_feature_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

...

```
Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/subdomain_feature_spec.rb:6 # subdomains redirects invalid accounts
```

**Relevant Files**

> *spec/features/subdomain_feature_spec.rb*

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'subdomains' do
  let!(:account) { create(:account_with_schema) }

  it 'redirects invalid accounts' do
    visit root_url(subdomain: 'random-subdomain')
    expect(page.current_url).to_not include('random-subdomain')
  end

  it 'allows valid accounts' do
    visit root_url(subdomain: account.subdomain)
    expect(page.current_url).to include(account.subdomain)
  end

  it 'forces user to login before accessing subdomain content' do
    visit root_url(subdomain: account.subdomain)
    expect(page).to have_content 'sign in or sign up before continuing'
  end
end
```

---

> *config/routes.rb*

```
class SubdomainPresent
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present?
  end
end

class SubdomainBlank
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank?
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints(SubdomainPresent) do
    root 'projects#index', as: :subdomain_root
    devise_for :users
  end

  # only allow certain routes when there isn't a subdomain
  constraints(SubdomainBlank) do
    root 'welcome#index'
    resources :accounts, only: [:new, :create]
  end
end
```

---

> *controllers/application_controller.rb*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :load_schema, :authenticate_user!

  private

  def load_schema
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!('public')
    return unless request.subdomain.present?

    account = Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
    if account
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(request.subdomain)
    else
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: :false)
    end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

---

> *controllers/welcome_controller.rb*

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :index

  def index
  end
end
```

---

> *spec/factories/accounts.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:subdomain) { |n| "subdomain#{n}" }

  factory :account do
    sequence(:subdomain) { |n| "subdomain#{n}" }
    association :owner, factory: :user

    factory :account_with_schema do
      after(:build) do |account|
        Apartment::Tenant.create(account.subdomain)
        Apartment::Tenant.switch!(account.subdomain)
      end
      after(:create) do |account|
        Apartment::Tenant.reset
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

> spec/rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end

# Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
#   Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
# end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Capybara rack_test driver ignores hostnames so you're not going to be able to test subdomain behavior with it, you'll need to run those tests with one of the drivers that utilizes/mimics a full browser (selenium, poltergeist, capybara-webkit).

Additionally you want to write and url/path check using the Capybara `have_current_path matcher` rather than `eq` with `current_url'

```
expect(page).not_to have_current_path(/random-subdomain/, url: true)
```

Comment: Going with the capybara-webkit route. Their documentation doesn't say where to make this adjustment....  

Set your Capybara Javascript driver to webkit:

`Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`

Comment: @BennyPaulino and then you'd need to tag the test as `js: true` metadata - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec  - or if you want all the tests to run using that driver you could set `Capybara.default_driver = :webkit`  - you'll probably also need to configure `database_cleaner` because of https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup .  Also you need to make sure that whatever hostname your `root_url(...)` calls are returning does resolve to the address Capybara is running the server on (usually 127.0.0.1)

Comment: [This article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/modern-applications-use-javascript-you-can-make) helped. It needs to go inside features/support/env.rb

Comment: @BennyPaulino features/support/env.rb would be when using Cucumber, you probably want the spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb since you appear to be using just straight RSpec --  basically you want it in the same file where you required capybara/rails

Comment: I decided to go with Poltergeist after further investigation, since there seemed to be fewer dependencies. The latest error appears to be related to your point about resolving the address. Does this require a Capybara customization in spec_helper or rails_helper?  
`  1) subdomains redirects invalid accounts`
    ` Failure/Error: visit root_url(subdomain: 'random-subdomain')
     
     Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
       Request to 'http://random-subdomain.example.com/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status

Comment: Added rails_helper.rb to show that having `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` doesn't resolve the "failed to reach server" error.

Comment: This helped to resolve the "failed to reach server" issue  -- 
https://gist.github.com/turadg/5399790